# Typescript 0.8.3.1 Compile-On-Save degraded and stopped working today

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, web-essentials

Visual Studio 2012, Typescript 0.8.3.1 Yesterday, I started having problem where, when I saved 1 .ts file, it would show me errors (about 6 in 3 files because they relied on the change I had just done), when I saved one of the other files that I went to fix the error it would none of the errors (even if I didn't fix).

When I rebooted, for the first 3 or 4 minutes, it showed no errors, but then 'suddenly' doing a save by adding and removing a space, the errors showed up, but then when I made a 'real' change, the js file did not change.

I can make any change I want and the js only changes if I exit VS and come back in, and when it reloads (I've tried this a few times) the js file is sometimes several changes out of date from the ts file, sometimes is based on the newest ts file.

I uninstalled the ts plugin and web essentials this morning and reinstalled (still 0.8.3.1).

No differences that I can see to the symptoms.

I have verified that both Visual Studio settings in Tools > Options > Text Editor > TypeScript > Project > Compile on Save settings are Unchecked and that the Webessentials one IS checked to compile on save.

There are no 'new' files and the only changes I've made in the past few days other than those noted above are to edit my existing ts files. Yesterday it appeared to be working fine until these anomalies started to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are describing sounds like either...

- A genuine bug in your code that isn't getting shown immediately
- A problem with the state of the incremental editor

If it is the latter, there are improvements coming in newer versions. If you need help checking for code problems you'll need to share the code or a cut down example that demos the problem.

Comment: Further testing, using the command line compiler. It appears I introduced a bug that caused 40 errors with the result that NO errors or changes in the js show up on the right hand panel in VS 2012, but they do show up in the command line compiler.

Comment: Strange - Web Essentials normally does a good job of that, displaying errors on the right-hand pane. All sorted now?

Comment: Yes. I've confirmed absolutely with several tests (creating 40+ errors with a single stroke) - when I get 'too many' errors, the right-hand panel reports NO errors OR it reports SOME errors but doesn't specify there are more, but tsc reports them properly in both cases. So - we've added to our protocol: 1. If compiles aren't working, run the command line to see if there are errors and 2. NEVER trust the right-hand panel, ALWAYS use the command line to double check before uploading to others. This also fixed a similar problem for a college. So...all good, hopefully .9 will handle it better.

Comment: As a side note - when I increased the number of errors to THOUSANDS, the 1st character of the ts file was underlined with a squiggly red line which, when hovering, said there were more than 100 errors, but in the cases above, there was no such squiggly line.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report to Web Essentials for this.